# How to download an image from url when a button clicked on android

Tags: android

I am trying to download the image file in a url when a button clicked. I have written this code that download automatically when an image url hit but i want to add a button and then when the button clicked download should start.

My java code.

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
if (url.endsWith(".jpg")){
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                         Uri.parse(url));
request.allowScanningByMediaScanner(); request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED); 
                 request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/Happy", "Happy.jpg");
                 DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                 dm.enqueue(request);
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", 
                         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            }
          view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are in webview, you can save the url somewhere in a field and when user tap on button, send the download request.

```
  public String downloadUrl;


  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
       if (url.endsWith(".jpg")){
            downloadUrl = url;
       }
       view.loadUrl(url);
       return true;
 }
```

And when user tap on button, you can initiate download request

```
btnDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // Download here using downloadUrl
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                     Uri.parse(downloadUrl));
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner(); 
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.
    Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED); 
             request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/Happy", "Happy.jpg");
             DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
             dm.enqueue(request);
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", 
                     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a button in the XML code and apply a function to the onClick parameter. You can do that via the Attributes GUI, or type it directly in the XML code.

The GUI interface (which will execute the playSpeech() method on a click):

[image]

The XML code (which will call callTheFunction()):

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:onClick="callTheFunction" />
```

Or you can do it with Java code, this way:

```
((Button) findViewById(R.id.button)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        callTheFunction();
    }
});
```

Note that the `callTheFunction()` or the `playSpeech()` methods in this example need to be created